# Prototype AJAX responsetext missing the javascript

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I can find the JS and HTML code in response by `alert()`. But i cannot append JS from response to `body` tag however HTML is appending fine.

```
new Ajax.Request(product_url, {
    method: 'post',
    onSuccess: function(transport) {
         $$('body')[0].insert(transport.responseText);
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you show what the response looks like, and then what evidence you have that the js is not appending?

Comment: I am sure about that, wondering from last 5 hrs and finally what the problem insert() this function internally implements evalScript() so this is the reason . and also appendChild() is not working there any other solution ?

Comment: That comment is very confusing to me.

Comment: in above question : insert() function internally implements evalScript(), so it removes the script from response

Comment: Is insert() a method you have written? I can't find any documentation for insert() as being a DOM node method (although there is an insertBefore()). If this is a method you've written please post the code for it.

Comment: here it is : http://prototypejs.org/api/element/insert

Comment: Oh sorry, just now noticed this was using the prototype library. Could you possibly use the node insertBefore() method instead? http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_insertbefore.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
      new Ajax.Request(product_url, {
           method: 'post',
          onSuccess: function(transport) {

               $$('body')[0].insert(new Element("div",{id:"popup"}));
               $('popup').innerHTML = transport.responseText;
      }
    });
```

this gives the solution.